# probability for maximal result in rolling $n$ dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $n$ symmetric dice. Calculate the probability that the maximal result is equal  to $k$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

First, the dice are symmetric so the chance to get any number is equal, so my $\Omega$ is symmetric. There are different dice, so I use ordered selections and two dice can show the same number so:

$$|\Omega| = 6^n$$

Now, I defined $A$ to be the max result equals to $K$, and I need to calculate $\frac {|A|}{6^n}$.

I don't know how to continue and would love for some help.
Thank you!

Comment: Grammar tip:  Die is singular, dice is plural, and dices is the third person singular form of the verb to dice, meaning to cut into small cubes.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $M_n$ denotes the maximum result by throwing $n$ fair dice then: $$P(M_n=k)=P(M_n\leq k)-P(M_n\leq k-1)$$
The terms on RHS are not difficult to find.

Observe that: $$\{M_n\leq k\}=\{D_1\leq k,\dots,D_n\leq k\}$$ where $D_i$ denotes the result of the $i$-th die.

Comment: I tried calculating $P(M_n≤k)$, and it turned out $nk/6$, which doesn't makes much sense.. any lead on that? thanks

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld If $A$ and $B$ are independent events then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$. This leads to $P(M_n\leq k)=\left(\frac{k}{6}\right)^n $. It seems that you wrongly went for $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$.